# How to loop through excel autofilter where a criteria refers to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through an autofilter where I have X number of columns and the filter in each column will be as per a criteria specified in another sheet

This is the working code and in this I have specified autofilters for 2 columns, in the actual data I have 50 columns and the criteria for field 2 depends on B2 and B3 in the worksheet named Shhet1, criteria for field 3 depends on C2 and C3 and so on uptil column 50

```
Sub Macro1()
   Sheets("Data").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("Data").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
   ActiveSheet.Range("Data").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

I have tried the following code but the use of cells.value is incorrect.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim i As Integer
    Sheets("Data").Select
For i = 2 To 3
ActiveSheet.Range("Data").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterValues()

    Dim iColumn As Integer
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim wksCriterias As Worksheet

    Set wksCriterias = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngData = Range("Data")

    With wksCriterias
        For iColumn = 2 To 3
            rngData.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
                               Criteria1:=Array(CStr(.Cells(2, iColumn)), CStr(.Cells(3, iColumn))), _
                               Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey JohnyL thanks for the reply.

This code throws an error at the criteria line.. My table is in The sheet named "Data", the table itself is named "Data" as well, where as the conditions on which the filter is to be applied are in "sheet1"

Comment: So, change names and all references to ranges at your will.

Comment: This code tells will filter data based on cells in the same worksheet right? If yes, how should I write .cells(,) to refer to cells from a different worksheet?